# MySQL GROUP BY with subquery (ies)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of orders in a date range, grouping by date but also counting some other records which occurred on the same date.

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
order_date,
DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%W') AS day, 
DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS orderdate, 
COUNT(orderID) As orders, 
a.something AS something
b.something AS something_else,
a.something + b.something AS total_somethings
FROM orders,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS something FROM other_table) AS a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS something FROM another_table) AS b,
GROUP BY order_date 
HAVING order_date >= '2014-01-01' AND order_date <= '2014-01-31' 
ORDER BY order_date ASC
```

It works OK but obviously, the subqueries count every single row.  The tables 'other_table' and 'another_table' both have date fields which I would like to use to limit the results for each row.

I tried changing the subqueries to something like :

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS something FROM other_table WHERE date_field = order_date) AS a,
```

but it's still counting every single row.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you run the sub-query by itself, do you get the expected count? SELECT COUNT(*) AS something FROM other_table WHERE date_field = order_date;

Comment: If I specify the date myself, eg WHERE date_field = '2014-01-01', then yes, I get the correct count for that particular day

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. The order_date column refers to the orders table. However, you cannot access this column within an "inline view". You should get an error unless there is another order_date column in the other_table.

Comment: Yeah, OK when I add an alias to order_date and try to use that in the subqueries, it does indeed give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following query, I grouped the `date_field` in `other_table` and `another_table` tables. Then, I joined with the `orders` table using the `date_field`. Does the following query work for you?

```
SELECT 
order_date,
DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%W') AS day, 
DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS orderdate, 
COUNT(orderID) As orders, 
a.something AS something
b.something AS something_else,
a.something + b.something AS total_somethings
FROM orders,
(SELECT date_field, COUNT(*) AS something FROM other_table GROUP BY date_field) AS a,
(SELECT date_field, COUNT(*) AS something FROM another_table GROUP BY date_field) AS b
WHERE order_date >= '2014-01-01' AND order_date <= '2014-01-31' 
AND order_date = a.date_field AND order_date = b.date_field
GROUP BY order_date 
ORDER BY order_date ASC;
```

Comment: I think that's done it, I'll have to double check but it all looks correct to me. Thanks for your help.